# JQuery Event On Clearing A Div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div that is used to display one of several wizard interfaces; which wizard is dependent upon a menu selection.

Unfortunately, if a user clicks a different menu option, the div is cleared and the new wizard is displayed. There is no chance to clean up the session (which I am using as a conversation scope).

Is there a way to trap the jquery .empty() command, in order to make sure I can clean up any mess before new content is displayed?

Comment: If it's your code that is calling the `empty()` function, why not trigger a custom event that some other module can listen for?

Comment: ↑↑↑ and if it's not your code, you could still override empty() method to add a callback option

Comment: Have you looked at promise.done? that would allow you to not process anything else until the empty() is finished http://api.jquery.com/promise/

Comment: @DarrenSweeney empty() isn't async

Comment: I've considered the custom event idea, and might still go with it. However, if wizard #1 listens for it, and wizard #2 listens for it, how do I know if the listener for #1 is processed before #2?

Answer (score 1):

With no real code it's hard to answer, but as I can see in docs empty() has no method for binding another function (http://api.jquery.com/empty/) - so my suggestion is to write own function for clearing and allow it's manipulation.

Another way could be with some "dirty form" handling (check if form changed and allow/disallow etc).